# How to remove a property of a CQ node in JAVA

Tags: aem

how can I remove the property of a node in JAVA code?
I have tried something like -

```
node.setProperty(propertyName, null);
```

Is there something specific which I can try?

Comment: Setting the value of a property to `null` is a correct way to remove it using the JCR API. Are you getting any errors? The example you've shown has an error in it, the name of the method is `setProperty` but I suppose that's just a typo in the question and not something that's actually in your code.

Answer (score 11):

Supposing that you have a typo with your "setProperty" method, you may be getting ambigous method error. You should do type casting if so:

```
node.setProperty(propertyName, (Value)null);
```

or use remove method

```
node.getProperty(propertyName).remove();
session.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing

```
session.save();
```