# Deleting a property in AEM 5

Tags: aem

I am trying to delete a property of a node. I could manually do it in the crx explorer but there is just way to many properties that I need to delete. Below is the sample code that is currently working. However just changing its value will not solve what I am trying to accomplish. Therefore my question is:

How can I delete a property of a node?

```
void deleteJob(Node node, Session jcr) throws RepositoryException {

           Node jobDescNode = (Node)jcr.getItem(node.getPath() + "/jcr:content/contentpar/jobsdescription");
           if(jobDescNode.hasProperty("foo")) {

               jobDescNode.setProperty("foo", "null");
               jcr.save();

           }

     }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995675/how-to-remove-the-property-of-a-cq-node-in-java/33999358#33999358

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are setting the value of the property to "null" instead of removing the property.

Use

```
jobDescNode.setProperty("foo", (String)null);
```

Check the [Node API](http://www.day.com/specs/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20javax.jcr.Value)) for more info.